# New badge idea: Dominator

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

I think there should be another badge created named `Dominator`, this would be used when a person dominates a particular tag. The particular metric used to determine that could go many ways but a one idea would be if that person meet the following criteria:

1. He is the leader in overall number of points for badge `XYZ`
2. His overall number of points is greater than the sum of the next 5 runner-ups.

As an example take a look at the [stats for ironpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=ironpython&sort=stats&pagesize=50). You can see that [Dino Viehland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114000/dino-viehland) is dominating that tag! Even though he is crushing everyone else in that category his overall number of points is less than 1500, so evidently he is kind of a specialist and should be recognized further for his contributions in that area.

Here are a couple other examples

1. [msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=msbuild&sort=stats&pagesize=50) ( *me :)* )
2. [expression-trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=expression-trees&sort=stats&pagesize=50)
3. [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=android&sort=stats&pagesize=50)

Comment: What happens when you lose your title to another user?

Comment: If you lose the position, then you obviously get the **Submissive** badge. @jon

Comment: LOL @jon. If you lose the title, I would think you still get to keep the badge.

Comment: Oh no, please no more badge floods for Jon Skeet.

Comment: I've just looked at those tags, and none of them - not even IronPython - matches your criteria. Perhaps you need to revisit the details?

Comment: There is no reason to have a badge that, should statistics change, cause the badge to become invalid.

Comment: @dboarman: Electorate is one of those.

Answer (score 8):

As much as I would appreciate another badge, I don't think this is really necessary since there are already [specialists badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) awarded on a per-tag basis.

Answer (score 4):

Can't say I'm a fan of the idea. We already have quite a few badges for answering questions well in an ordinary kind of way:

- Nice answer
- Good answer
- Great answer
- Guru
- Enlightened
- Tag badge (silver)
- Tag badge (gold)

If you're that far ahead in a tag, the chances are you'll have quite a few of those... and of course the rep from all those votes. Do we really need anything else?

(I haven't checked, but I suspect there aren't many tags where I'd actually get this... I tend to be active in popular tags, so the next 5 in each of those tags would probably outweigh me. However, I completely agree with the comments suggesting that introducing extra badges favouring me would usually be a bad idea :)

Comment: On the other hand, *nice answer*, *guru* and many others favor people like you who are active in popular tags. It's much harder to get those badges for more obscure tags.

Comment: @Georg: That's true...

Answer (score 1):

Great answer so far. A couple of thoughts from a slightly different perspective:

I personally don't like the sound of Dominator. First thing I consider is how this badge is perceived. Those badges such as Guru, Nice Answer, etc. are very relevant. Dominator is not. Next, consider the abuse that a badge name Dominator might incur. Quality of answers is so much more important than quantity. Let's keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not thrilled with the idea of another badge for Jon Skeet. (No offense, Jon. You do deserve them.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this badge should also be awarded if you're a robot who goes back in time to try to ask the questions you know to be popular so that you become the user with the highest rep.

Be sure to post "I'll be back" here on Meta and mind the grandfather paradoxes.

Oh...Err...Nevermind. If the user gets to keep the badge then it's not different in usefulness than the badges you can earn currently per tag.

If you don't get to keep the badge then that changes the badge system. It'd be more like an award or trophy that gets passed around. StackOverflow is competitive enough as it is, I don't think I'd want the competition solidified like that

Comment: That is the Terminator badge. If you have come back in time to answer all questions and take over the world, you will receive the Terminator Badge.